# How to add a JDBC request sampler in JMeter-5

Tags: database, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In previous versions of JMeter it was possible to add a JDBC Request simply by right-clicking the Test Plan and selecting **Add > Sampler > JDBC Request**.

How to do that in JMeter 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still do that in JMeter 5.0.

Most likely, you forgot to add Thread Group first. Samplers can only be added as child of Thread Group (or Logic Controller, or Test Fragment).

Answer (score 3):

You can add Sampler under Thread Group similar to previous version,

The **sort** of the samplers (and other menus) changed. JMeter 5:

[image]

Old JMeter 3.3:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

Normally [Apache JMeter JDBC](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_jdbc) plugins set should come with JMeter installation, make sure to download JMeter from [official downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page as it might be the case your installation is somehow broken.

It should be enough to download http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jmeter/ApacheJMeter_jdbc/5.0/ApacheJMeter_jdbc-5.0.jar file and drop it to `lib/ext` folder of your JMeter installation. After JMeter restart you should be able to see JDBC test elements.

You can also install `jmeter - JDBC Support` plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image]